# Why do so many websites write "earn minimum wage" when "wage" is a countable noun?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

When I searched from [the NOW corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/), I found that there are more instances of "earn minimum wage" than "earn **the** minimum wage", with many results from big US news websites. Why is this?

According to most dictionaries, *wage* is a countable noun, so "earn minimum wage" must be incorrect.

But I do find that it sounds more natural. My guess is that "minimum wage" has become a fixed expression itself, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Wage" is a countable noun - but "*minimum wage*" is a different, compound noun.

'Minimum wage' isn't really countable in most contexts because there is only one minimum wage (at least, only one which might apply - around the world, different economies set their own minimum wage).

You certainly could say "I earn *the* minimum wage", to mean you earn the equivalent of it. But it works without the article because it can be seen as *abstract* - you can't actually hold the minimum wage in your hand, but you can hold *your* earnings. Similarly, you might say "the room is at *maximum capacity*", to mean that *the* prescribed maximum has been met.

Consider a situation where an employer has different staff on different salaries, some full-time, some part-time - they all have different *wages*. But *minimum wage* is not actually any person's wage - it is just a single prescribed amount against which wages must measure up to. In fact, a person's 'wage' is usually the entire amount they earn, weekly, monthly or annually. But the 'minimum wage' is usually a prescribed hourly rate, so they really are not the same thing at all.

Comment: “In the UK, the minimum wages for 18 year olds and 21 year olds are different .” Is quite reasonable but a very special case.

Comment: @gnasher729 I'd have to say no. "The minimum wage is different for 18 and 21 year olds". As I've explained, 'minimum wage' is a concept, it's not usually counted.